# How to find sibling that has focused child in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following markup and want to give a style to `input-inner-button` when the `select` is focused, how can I do that in `CSS/SCSS`?

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="x">x</option>
      <option value="y">y</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-inner-button-group">
    <div class="input-inner-button">Inner Button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

update: I need the solution to be supported in Chrome, FF, IE back to 10, and Edge.

Comment: Simply use Javascript

Comment: @ThanveerShah - I disagree. If there is a CSS only solution, that's much better.

Comment: "IF", But for the way he has structured the code, there isn't a CSS solution

Comment: @dwjohnston With the given markup there isn't

Answer (score 3):

You can use the newer [**`:focus-within`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) pseudo selector on the `select` container. (see [`here`](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within) for current support)

> The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has received focus or contains an element that has received focus.

See demo below:

```css
.input-wrapper > div:first-child:focus-within + div .input-inner-button {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div>
    <select>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="x">x</option>
      <option value="y">y</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-inner-button-group">
    <div class="input-inner-button">inner button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not well supported by every browser - https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within

Comment: @Sylwek yeah its not widely supported - you can see that I've included that in my answer :)

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that. But good to know that there is such pseudo-class :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's not possibel with css exactly in your case (solution that will be supported by every browser). You have to use JS or you can remove `<div>` that is as parent of `<select>` and you can use mix of pseudo class `:focus` and `+` selector

```css
select:focus + .input-inner-button-group .input-inner-button {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <select>
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="x">x</option>
      <option value="y">y</option>
    </select>
  <div class="input-inner-button-group">
    <div class="input-inner-button">my inner button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This IS possible in CSS - if I understand your question - you want to change the styling of the inner button  when the select has focus.

**You can use the :focus pseudoselector and the direct sibling combinator ("+") in css**

All you have to do is remove the wrapping div around the select (so that it is a true sibling of the .input-inner-button-group) and then when the select is focussed - the contents of the next div (sibling) can be targeted. Then you have to go into that div to get the inner div.

I have added a button to demonstrate and put a margin top on it so that it is clear of the select when opened.

```css
.input-inner-button-group {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.input-wrapper select:focus + .input-inner-button-group .input-inner-button button {
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <select>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="x">x</option>
    <option value="y">y</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-inner-button-group">
    <div class="input-inner-button">
     <button type="button">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```